# What is a regexp (in Python format) to strip @ mentions?

Tags: python, regex

I have been fussing with this for 30 minutes at Reg101 without luck.

An @ mention is simply an alphanumeric word, optionally with underlines. No other punctuation is allowed. The word is bounded by a newline, whitespace or punctuation. (You might recognize this as the format used by Twitter and many other community platforms...) For example, `@my_name`, `@joe123`, `@joesmith`, `@fuzzymonkey_`.

---

Example input strings:

- `Okay okay  coffee it is :-) @justcoffeezurich`
- `Okay @justcoffeezurich okay  coffee it is :-)`
- `@justcoffeezurich Okay okay  coffee it is :-)`
- `Okay okay  coffee it is :-) @justcoffeezurich @coffeefiend`
- `Okay okay @justcoffeezurich  coffee it is :-) @coffeefiend`

For all of those input string examples, the output is all the same:

- `Okay okay  coffee it is :-)`

---

Or another example, with an email address (which is not an @ mention!):

- `Okay okay  coffee it is, email me@me.com :-) @justcoffeezurich`

Output string:

- `Okay okay  coffee it is, email me@me.com :-)`

Note that the @ mention(s) might be anywhere in the string, and there can be more than one. I just want to kill 'em all.

Comment: Are there any occasions where an @ should be allowed, e.g., e-mail addresses? Can you be more specific about exactly what the pattern looks like that should be removed?

Comment: Use [`" ".join([x for x in s.split() if not x.startswith('@')])`](https://ideone.com/EXTuuC)

Comment: All words that start with "@" will be removed

Comment: Email addresses should be fine-- adding a couple more example input strings now. I can't use Python code; I have to use a regex (in Python format).

Comment: This question currently is liable to **downvotes** as you haven't given enough exceptional cases. The negative score at this time means urgent attention is required. Please edit this question to address when is an at-sign a mention and reply back when you appropriately edited your question.

Comment: Urgent attention is needed!

Comment: Ah. I am not sure what is needed here. What are "exceptional cases"? I tried to find some information about this in the Stack Overflow help section and could not. I gave a bunch of examples in my original question; if that is not enough, I edited it to adapt the definition you gave.

Comment: Hello @Mulliganaceous please let me know if you believe my question needed further editing...

Comment: Exceptional cases are all @ not followed by spaces, which includes email addresses. Also note that some email addresses may contain spaces, but as of now not mind on it. On your question, **just define** what constitute a @-mention and when a @ does not count.

Comment: @Eric are these @-mentions based on StackOverflow @-mentions? I want to bring help and improvement to your post

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't adequately explained when a '@' constitutes an at-mention, I''ll say that the definition of a '@' mention is:

- The token begins with '@', meaning it is not preceded by a space, or it is a the beginning of a string
- After the '@', it is followed by consecutive word characters
- This definition is simpler than then one used on StackExchange - see ["How do comment @replies work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on Meta SE.

Consider this regex `((^@\w*)|( @\w*))` with the global `g` modifier

(the string form is `"((^@\\w*)|( @\\w*))"`

1. The word *begins* with the at-sign mentions meaning before the word it is either start of string o a whitespace `\s`.

   - `(^@\w+)` deals with cases where the mention is at the beginning of the string.
   - `( @\w+)` deals with cases where the mention is at any other places.
2. Followed by a number of consecutive word characters.
3. Perform union of initial `(^@\w*)` and `( @\w*)`.

Here are some sample tests and its matches from Reg101: https://regex101.com/r/8pGDkv/1, each line is considered a new string

Hope that definition is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Your examples in RegEx101 look great, but I see they are capturing the @ mentions. My goal is to strip the @ mentions and output a string without them. Is it possible to tweak the formula to accomplish this? Thanks again.

Comment: @Eric It is possible to tweak. The Python regex allows you to remove characters that match this regex.